# Limiting size of require statement when using ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Sometimes I look back at my code or someone else's and see these crazy long `require` statements - sometimes, hundreds of lines long.

Some of the options for limiting the size of the `require` statement that I have seen are to:

- Componentize the functions
- Use promises or callbacks

Is it actually a big deal that the `require` statement gets so long?

Many aspects of a web map using the ArcGIS API for Javascript simply will not work unless scripts are run within the `require` statement.

Here's an example of some code I've inherited with a ridiculously long `require` statement. The full length is actually 300 lines long.

[image]